# BinData: define structure based on first two bytes

Tags: ruby, bindata

I'm using Ruby and trying to read binary data from a TCP interface. The message received contains a header and a payload. The payload is determined by an id from the header.

This is an example:

```
class TCPmessage < BinData:: Record

  class PayloadType_1 < BinData::Record
    uint8 :payloadType_1
    # more payload data
  end

  class PayloadType_2 < BinData::Record
    uint8 :payloadType_2
    # more payload data
  end

  uint8 :payload_id

  array :payload, :type => <<Here I need to select "PayloadType_1" or "PayloadType_2" based on the "payload_id" from above>>, ...

end
```

I tried a few variants but only came up with the following solution:

```
class TCPmessage < BinData:: Record

  class PayloadType_1 < BinData::Record
    uint8 :payload_id
    uint8 :payloadType_1
    # more payload data
  end

  class PayloadType_2 < BinData::Record
    uint8 :payload_id
    uint8 :payloadType_2
    # more payload data
  end

  uint8 :payload_id
end
```

In the main program I first read `payload_id` and then use a `case` statement to choose which class to instantiate next:

```
x = TCPmessage.new
case x.read("TCPmessage").payload_id.to_s
when "1"
  y = TCPmessage::PayloadType_1.new
when "2"
  y = TCPmessage::PayloadType_2.new
end
y.read("TCPmessage")
```

I'm sure there is another solution using the compound types (arrays/choices) from BinData gem but I could not see it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether the BinData gem already had that feature back when this question was asked, but for a declarative approach, you'd want to use its [Choice](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata/wiki/CompoundTypes#choices) type.

For your case, probably like so:

```
require 'bindata'

class PayloadType_1 < BinData::Record
  uint8 :type_one_byte
  # more payload data for type 1
end

class PayloadType_2 < BinData::Record
  uint8 :type_two_byte
  # more payload data for type 2
end

class TCPmessage < BinData::Record
  uint8 :payload_id
  choice :payload, selection: :payload_id do
    array 1, type: :payloadType_1, read_until: :eof
    array 2, type: :payloadType_2, read_until: :eof
  end
end

puts TCPmessage.read "\x01ABC" # {:payload_id=>1, :payload=>[{:type_one_byte=>65}, {:type_one_byte=>66}, {:type_one_byte=>67}]}
puts TCPmessage.read "\x02DEF" # {:payload_id=>2, :payload=>[{:type_two_byte=>68}, {:type_two_byte=>69}, {:type_two_byte=>70}]}
```

Note that `selection: :payload_id` is a shortcut for `selection: lambda { payload_id }`. So if you actually need to index the choices by strings for some reason, you could

```
  # [...]
  choice :payload, selection: lambda { payload_id.to_s } do
    array "1", type: :payloadType_1, read_until: :eof
    array "2", type: :payloadType_2, read_until: :eof
  end
  # [...]
```

Comment: It's sad that a high-quality answer like this does not get more attention. `choice` is absolutely the way to go in this case.

Comment: @amenthes That's not unusual for answers given a long time after the question was asked. I'm glad you found it useful, though. :-)

Comment: Very much so! I pressed the upvote button so hard, it should yield +20, but that's not how it works :D. Maybe @danizgod accepts this answer when he finds this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything really wrong with the way you're doing it, given the little we know about what you're trying to do.

I'd write it a bit differently, but it's not going to make much difference functionally:

```
x = TCPmessage.new
y = case x.read("TCPmessage").payload_id
    when 1
      TCPmessage::PayloadType_1.new
    when 2
      TCPmessage::PayloadType_2.new
    end
y.read("TCPmessage")
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to choose the type of the array at runtime based on the header value.

Comment: Yes, that I could tell. I couldn't see any way to return a different class based on the value of the header in BinData's `Choice` methods. It's easy to return one of its types, as their docs show. Returning an "alien" type isn't documented and is what you need.